# Determine values for no soln, unique soln, infinite many solns for a

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  a^2-a&0&a&a^2\\
  0&1-a^2&a^2&-a\\
  0&a^2-1&a&a\\
  a^2-a&0&a&2a
\end{array}
\right] $$

Determine the values of a for the system to have:
(1) no solution; 
(2) a unique solution; 
(3) infinitely many solns with one parameter; 
(4) infinitely many solns with two parameters

**What I have done:**
I have reduced the matrix down to row-echelon form, which gives me the following:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  a^2-a&0&a&a^2\\
  0&1-a^2&a^2&-a\\
  0&0&a+a^2&0\\
  0&0&0&2a-a^2
\end{array}
\right] $$

I have also found:
(1) no solution; a /= 0 or a/= 2
(2) unique solution; a = 2
(3) infinitely many solns with one parameter; a = 0

However, i'm not sure how to proceed with (4), and am unsure if (1) - (3) is correct. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure there's only one parameter for $a=0$? Also, trying $a=\pm 1$ should give some clue.

Comment: @DavidCheng i just realise there's two parameters for a = 0! I've tried +-1, it renders the system inconsistent due to the last row. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You're perfectly right.  Option (3) never occurs. @DavidCheng What's special about $a=\pm1$?